# Oracle takes more time to export csv from table

Tags: oracle11g

Oracle takes more time to export csv from table,i have tried with UTL_FILE & spool both takes more time,if there are any other way in coding for the fastest export?

Comment: "more time" implies that you are comparing it to something that takes "less time".  What is that comparison?  I'd guess that either spooling via SQL*Plus or writing to a file using `utl_file` could be tuned depending on what is taking the time.  You might try Tom Kyte's Pro*C SQL Unloader utility as well http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteflat.html

Comment: my comparison:
In oracle 
No of Recorsds:1253259
Time Taken:25 mins
No of colomns:4

In MSSQL
MSSQL takes only 45 sec to export (using xmd_shell bcp)

I refered to your given link, but we can't use this in our scenario because
We need to export csv from table dynamically while replication .

So i need any alternative solution similar to  bcp or any other which can be achieved through coding

Comment: My environment:

DB:Oracle 11g

Exported CSV using UTL_FILE

No of Recorsds:1253259
Time Taken:25 mins
os:Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
No of colomns:4
Datatype:varchar
Disk set up details:
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pr--vg-root  225G   28G  187G  13% /
//serverip/share  450G   47G  381G  11% /location/
/dev/sda1                   236M   39M  185M  18% /boot
My expectation:It should happen 45-60 secs
Note:But MSSQL takes only 45 sec to export (using xmd_shell bcp)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why none of the implementations on the linked page would work for you.  All three are dynamic.  None would interfere with any replication technology I can think of.  Not knowing exactly how you built the `utl_file` code Tom wrote is probably more efficient than the code you wrote (Tom's code is more efficient than most, that's not a slam on you).

Comment: Hi cave the problem is where i write,when i write to the file local drive it writes in 1 minutes,while i write it on network mapped drive it takes more than 20 minutes. Size of the csv created is around 75 MB. I tried my mounting the drive to windows and tried to add in oracle but oracle could it understand my mounted path i.e Z:\. Is there anything i can try other than this. Note- I need to use the mapped drive or server storage only

Comment: OK.  So the problem isn't actually with generating the CSV file, it's with writing to the mapped drive?  Are you running SQL Server and Oracle on the same server writing to the same mapped drive?  If not, it sounds like you have a network problem (you seem to say that generating the file on the mapped server is slow in one breath and that it doesn't work in another which is confusing).  You'd want to use the UNC path for the Oracle directory object if you are using `utl_file`.  You'd also need to ensure that the Windows user running the Oracle service has permissions to that drive.